# Flutter DropdownMenuItem: how to iterate

Tags: loops, flutter

folks.

Consider the DropdownMenuItem items:

"USA, India, Germany, Brazil"

I have a json with a value (for ex: Brazil). When the user open the screen, I'd like to iterate the DropdownMenuItem and show the "Brazil" item as the selected item.

Very simple :))

Tks.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate the dropdown with `List.generate(index, builder);` constructor. And there there is value parameter in DropDownButton & DropDownMenuItem. The value parameter in DropDownButton is selected value and value parameter in DropDownMenuItem is value of that item. Example is below.

```
//outside of build method
List<String> values = <String>['USA', 'India', 'Germany', 'Brazil'];
String selectedValue = 'Brazil';

//inside of build method
DropdownButton<String>(
    value: selectedValue,
    items: List.generate(
        values.length,
        (index) => DropdownMenuItem(
            value: values[index], child: Text(values[index]))),
    onChanged: (newValue) {
      selectedValue = newValue;
      setState(() {});
    });
```

P.S. use this inside stageful widget, so that state can be changed when value changed.

Comment: Tks, Mohamed. Solved!!